# Python: Test if x is a particular method object

Tags: python

I have a python function that looks roughly like this:

```
def f(x):
    [...]
    g(x)
```

Sometimes, for reasons beyond my control `x` is of type `<bound method A.b of <A: a>>` . `g()` is in a 3rd party library and can not handle this argument and throws an exception. So what I want to do before `g()` is called is to test for this case and do something else instead:

```
def f(x):
    [...]
    if x == A.b:
       doSometingElse()
    else:
       g(x)
```

Now, `==` does not seem to work as it is never true. What is the correct way to test if my variable `x` contains the method `A.b`?

Comment: try `is_instance`. or use `try...catch` to catch that exception.

Comment: `try...catch` is not an option in my case because it aborts `g()` prematurely

Comment: For `isinstance(x, Y)` what exactly would `Y` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in the class is turned into a bound method when accessed on an object, or an unbound method when accessed on the class.  In Python 2, both types have a **func** attribute that refer to the function. So your test could look like:

```
if x.__func__ is A.b.__func__:
```

In Python 3 it's a little easier:

```
if x.__func__ is A.b:
```

Comment: If you don't care about python2.5 and below (who does?) `.__func__` also works in python2.6 and python2.7

Comment: This does the trick. I only tested the Python 3 case as that's what I'm currently using

Comment: @AnthonySottile good point, I didn't realize! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to throw a try except in there

```
def f(x):
    [...]
    try:
        g(x)
    except:
        do something else
```

this would be the easiest way to handle it.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work because it causes `g()` to abort before it has done all it needs to do do.